# How to install intellisense for bootstrap 3 in netbeans?

Tags: netbeans, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using netbeans for developing a website in java. I am using bootstrap 3 CDN but it does not show me any hints (intellisense). May be it is not installed in it so how can I install bootstrap intellisense in netbeans?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK there are no plugins for the Bootstrap intellisense plugin for Netbeans.

> I am using bootstrap 3 CDN but it does not show me any hints (intellisense).

Yes, this will not work and this applies to other CSS frameworks like Foundation too.

When you're developing the website on local computer just download Bootstrap CSS and JS files. Include it in your project. Once you complete the code just replace those local file links with CDN and host it on a live server.

When you're using local files Netbeans will give you intellisence without any problems.

P.S: If you're interested check [BootstrapPalette](http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/58833/bootstrappalette) plugin for Netbeans

Comment: Glad to here that. Happy coding.